# Amazon Aurora in Mule

Tags: mysql, mule, amazon-aurora

How to connect to Amazon Aurora (MySQL) from mule 4? 
Basically, I need to connect and read data from MySql instance.
can anyone help me with a sample configuration for it?

Comment: The connection parameters of the Amazon Aurora DB not enough to configure the MuleSoft Database Connector and connect?

Comment: can we directly use the db credentials of mysql db to connect?

Comment: Ideally, you should. Amazon Aurora is just AWS' version of a SQL DB. In fact, if you check the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2Aurora.Steps.ConnectAurora.html) for connecting to Amazon Aurora, it mentions that you can use the usual SQL driver, which means that the MuleSoft DB connector should support it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL databases are supported via the Database Connector. Mule 4 documentation available here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db-connector-index